# In python, how can I get a value from a Gtk.entry entry box and pass it to a variable?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

I've been struggling for a two days now to get the user input from entry3, entry2, and entry 1 and define 3 variables l, w, and h with it. No matter what I try I cannot get `Gtk.Entry.get_text()` to recognize my entrys! Here is my code; it launches a nice little gui I created for solving Pythagorean theorem problems.

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import math
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
a = False
b = False
c = True #changed for test
l = 0
w = 0
h = 0
ans = 0

class MyGI(Gtk.Window):
    def gtk_main_quit(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)
        raise SystemExit
    def solve(self, widget):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        l = self.builder.get_object('entry3')
        float(l)
        print l
        if a == True:
            ans = math.pow(h, 2) - math.pow(w, 2)
            ans = math.sqrt(ans) 
            print(ans)
        if b == True:
            ans = math.pow(h, 2) - math.pow(l, 2)
            ans = math.sqrt(ans) 
            print(ans)
        if c == True:
            ans = math.pow(l, 2) + math.pow(w, 2)
            ans = math.sqrt(ans) 
            print(ans)
    def a_x(self, widget):
        a = True
        b = False
        c = False
        print a
    def b_x(self, widget):
        a = False
        b = True
        c = False
    def c_x(self, widget):
        a = False
        b = False
        c = True
    def entree(self, widget):
        pass
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("pythag.glade")
builder.connect_signals(MyGI())
window = builder.get_object("window1")    #old window method
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Any help is appreciated, I am at the end of my rope. This is the only problem left to solve

Answer (score 2):

You aren't supposed to use GtkBuilder like that. You're supposed to use it once per `.ui` file, when you create your window (so, for example, in the `__init__` of your class), and then `get_object()` everything into instance variables.

My Python is rusty, so, something like this:

```
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        builder = Gtk.Builder.new_from_file("pythag.glade")
        builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.window = builder.get_object("window1")
        self.entry3 = builder.get_object("entry3")
        self.window.show_all()
    def solve(self, widget):
        float(self.entry3)
```

To get the text from a GtkEntry, use the syntax `entryObject.props.text`.

Comment: Errrr I'm confused as to why @elya5's edits were rejected; they're correct and fix actual errors in my code. I added them manually anyway.

Comment: I'm confused as well :D

Comment: `self.entry3.props.text`

Comment: Right, that too. Thanks.